# PHP for each - else always returns else value

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, if-statement

Im using the code below to send a report however when i add the `else` statement that is all that is returned even when the if statement is true.

can anyone explain why this? i dont think ive ever had this issue before?

```
foreach ( $result as $page ) {
 $date1 = new DateTime($page->start_date);
 $date2 = new DateTime($page->end_date);

 if (strtotime($page->start_date) >= strtotime('today') && strtotime($page->start_date) < strtotime('tomorrow')) {

     $email_content .=  '<span style=" background-colour: #777777; font-size: 1em; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:#202020;"><strong>' . $page->post_title . ' </strong></span>';

     $email_content .=  '<span style=" font-size: 1em; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:#00b200;"><strong>Order By '  . $date1->format('d-m-y') . ' ' . '</strong></span>';

     $email_content .=  '<div style="  font-size: 1em; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:#cc0000;"><strong>For Delivery '  . $date2->format('d-m-y') . '</strong></div><br>' . '<br>';

 }else {
     $email_content =  '<span style=" background-colour: #777777; font-size: 1em; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:#202020;"><strong>tester </strong></span>';
 }
}
```

thanks for reading :)

Comment: you are using start_date twice - did you mean to use end_date in your second comparison?

Comment: code is not formated :) :) @jonny can you print the output of else condition to so that we can get exact idea.

Comment: @trevor  is correct `start_date` used twice and `end_date` doesn't used

Comment: the start date is meant to be in there twice as its getting events based on the start. the problem is when I add the "else" that is all that returned even when there are dates to be returned

Comment: Are you sure the condition could be true ? Could you add `var_dump(strtotime($page->start_date)); var_dump(strtotime('today')); var_dump(strtotime('tomorrow')); echo '<br />';` in your `foreach` and show us the output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you loop through, your $email_content variable is getting overwritten in the else statement.  You are appending in the if with the . but overwriting in the else.  Try updating your code to this:

```
        foreach ( $result as $page ) {
     $date1 = new DateTime($page->start_date);
     $date2 = new DateTime($page->end_date);

     if (strtotime($page->start_date) >= strtotime('today') && strtotime($page->start_date) < strtotime('tomorrow')) {

         $email_content .=  '<span style=" background-colour: #777777; font-size: 1em; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:#202020;"><strong>' . $page->post_title . ' </strong></span>';

         $email_content .=  '<span style=" font-size: 1em; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:#00b200;"><strong>Order By '  . $date1->format('d-m-y') . ' ' . '</strong></span>';

         $email_content .=  '<div style="  font-size: 1em; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:#cc0000;"><strong>For Delivery '  . $date2->format('d-m-y') . '</strong></div><br>' . '<br>';
    }else {
         $email_content .=  '<span style=" background-colour: #777777; font-size: 1em; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color:#202020;"><strong>tester </strong></span>';

 }
}
```